# How to select up to and including a match with a regex

Tags: regex

Given the strings :

```
App Name.app (pkg)
AppName.app (app)
App_Name.app (pkg)
LongApp Name.app (app)
```

This `/^(.*?)\.app/` matches the names excluding the `.app`. How do I match the names including the `.app`?

resulting in :

```
App Name.app
AppName.app
App_Name.app
LongApp Name.app
```

Comment: `(.*?)` is the matched group, if you want the `.app` to be included - you should add it to the matching group: `(.*?\.app)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(.*?\.app)
```

This should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^(.*)\s\(
```

It group the values from your input